# I want to fetch this data year wise

Tags: sql, inner-join

```
Select
    CIDetail.Itemname, 
    sum(CIDetail.TaxAmount+ CIDetail.LineAmount) As [TotalAmount]  
From
    CIDetail (Nolock) 
    INNER JOIN CIHeader On CIDetail.InvoiceNo= CIHeader.InvoiceNo   
Where
    CIHeader.InvoiceDate Between '2010-04-01' AND '2014-04-01'
Group By 
    CIDetail.Itemname
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Show an example of data and how you want to see it.

Comment: Now im fatching this data Between '2010-04-01' AND '2014-04-01' but now i want to fatch this data year wise

Comment: Do you mean all the data for e.g. 2010?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add to the query a order by clause. Here as you are saying that you want it by date, I will assume that one **itemname** has only one **InvoiceDate**. And thus its **max** will have the same value. You will have to do it as follows

```
Select CIDetail.Itemname,

sum(CIDetail.TaxAmount+ CIDetail.LineAmount) As [TotalAmount],

From CIDetail (Nolock) INNER JOIN CIHeader

On CIDetail.InvoiceNo= CIHeader.InvoiceNo

Where CIHeader.InvoiceDate Between '2010-04-01' AND '2014-04-01' Group By

CIDetail.Itemname

Order By max(CIHeader.InvoiceDate) ASC
```

Comment: "CIHeader.InvoiceDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @SANJOG thanks! I had missed that. Made the changes. Have put it in a Agg function

Answer (score 0):

Have a derived table where you use ANSI SQL's `EXTRACT` to get the year part out of the date, and also add the amounts together. At main level you do `GROUP BY` both Itemname and year:

```
Select Itemname, "year", SUM(Amount) as TotalAmount
from
(
    CIDetail.Itemname, 
    extract(year from CIHeader.InvoiceDate) as "year",
    CIDetail.TaxAmount + CIDetail.LineAmount As Amount  
From
    CIDetail (Nolock) 
    INNER JOIN CIHeader On CIDetail.InvoiceNo= CIHeader.InvoiceNo   
) dt
Group By 
    Itemname, "year"
```

No dbms tagged in question, but if your dbms doesn't support `EXTRACT`, try `YEAR(CIHeader.InvoiceDate)` for example, or something else.